# Reset textbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a input textbox like this:

```
<input type="text" id="searchField" name="searchField" />
```

How can I set the value of the textfield using javascript or jQuery?

You would think this was simple but I've tried the following:

**Using defaultvalue**

```
var a = document.getElementById("searchField");
a.value = a.defaultValue;
```

**Using jQuery**

```
jQuery("#searchField").focus( function()
{ 
  $(this).val(""); 
} );
```

**Using js**

```
document.getElementById("searchField").value = "";
```

None of them are doing it... :/

Comment: What is **myinput.defaultValue** ?

Comment: On which event you are resetting the value?

Comment: I have a anchor link which calls some javascript method onClick. The rest of the js in there runs fine, but this code doesn't want to work. I think I've got something else interfering with it :/

Comment: Could show us a a bit more of your code. The context in wich this is use? maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: document.getElementById("searchField").value = "", this should do wat u want

Comment: Have you tried to trace your code with alert. The error might occur above in the code.

Comment: Just found it, for some reason a method within that method, which does call, is stopping anything from running after it! +1 for the alert comment. Add it to your answer my friend and you'll get the tick ;)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

In Javascript :

```
document.getElementById('searchField').value = '';
```

In  jQuery :

```
$('#searchField').val('');
```

That should do it

Answer (score 10):

With jQuery, I've found that sometimes using [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to clear the value of a textbox has no effect, in those situations I've found that using [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) does the job

```js
$('#searchField').attr("value", "");
```

Comment: I haven't done extensive testing on this, but it seems that this method is the only one that works with elements that are dynamically created and injected into the DOM, for instance the jQuery UI combobox. `.val()` does not work

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this:

```
$("#searchField").focus(function() {
    $(this).val("");
});
```

It has to work. Otherwise it probably never gets focused.

Comment: Maybe you need to give us more of your code because i tested my script and [it works fine](http://jsbin.com/opesel/5/). You probably made a mistake where you expect it the least. By the way, if you want a placeholder in your text input you could use: `<input type="text" (id, name, etc) placeholder="hello" />`

Comment: Turns out something else was stopping the script being called. This wasn't a ideal solution though as it would only empty the box when the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 1):

To set value

```
 $('#searchField').val('your_value');
```

to retrieve value

```
$('#searchField').val();
```

Comment: This is what I've been trying, I've got a feeling it might be something else interfering with it :/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but this may help clarify:

```
$('#searchField')
    .val('')// [property value] e.g. what is visible / will be submitted
    .attr('value', '');// [attribute value] e.g. <input value="preset" ...
```

Changing [attribute value] has no effect if there is a [property value].
(user || js altered input)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
$('#searchField').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, select the element. You can usually use the ID like this:

```
$("#searchField"); // select element by using "#someid"
```

Then, to set the value, use `.val("something")` as in:

```
$("#searchField").val("something"); // set the value
```

Note that you should only run this code when the element is *available*. The usual way to do this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // execute when everything is loaded
    $("#searchField").val("something"); // set the value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("#searchField").focus(function()
{ 
    this.value = ''; 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

this is might be a possible solution

```
void 0 != document.getElementById("ad") &&       (document.getElementById("ad").onclick =function(){
 var a = $("#client_id").val();
 var b = $("#contact").val();
 var c = $("#message").val();
 var Qdata = { client_id: a, contact:b, message:c }
 var respo='';
     $("#message").html('');

return $.ajax({

    url: applicationPath ,
    type: "POST",
    data: Qdata,
    success: function(e) {
         $("#mcg").html("msg send successfully");

    }

})
```

});