# Dynamically arrange words into array based on task number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a language learning RPG. A task will be for a user to select words from a word bank that get placed into a text box. Once they submit the words, I want to parse the string to check the word order to make sure they have constructed the sentence in a grammatical way.

[image]

Originally, I was going to hardcode each sentence per task. But I would prefer to have a database full of single words... and based on the current task, the task would dictate how the words should be loaded into the array to be compared against the user's input.

For example:

**Task 1:** User needs to type in "Ni Hao Wo Shi." The task # will do something like `wordOrder.push("Ni", "Hao", "Wo", "Shi")` from the word bank (which is an object `words` that stores all words in an object).

**Task 2:** User types in "Wo Shi Dan." Again, the task # this time will tell it to clear the array, and load it as `wordOrder.push("Wo", "Shi", "Dan")`...

But I also don't want to have a bunch of `if else` blocks that hardcode which words to push into the array, because then I might as well hardcode the sentences. I would rather they dynamically be pulled from the `words` object and put in order like

**Task 1:** wordOrder(0, 2, 1, 3)

**Task 2:** wordOrder(1, 2, 3)

Javascript:

```
var words = {
    "task1" :
    {
        'Ni'    : 'you',
        'Wo'    : 'I',
        'Hao'   : 'good',
        'Shi'   : 'am'  
    },
    "task2" :
    {
        'Xie Xie' : 'Thanks',
        'Bu' : 'No',
        'Ke Qi' : 'Manners'
    }
}

/*Check player sentence input to see if grammar is correct*/
function submitMe() {
    var input = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
    //if quest = 1, the words in the word bank should be checked in the order specified by quest
    //compare input against word order of that quest
   if ($.trim(input) == getWordOrder(currentTask)) {
        alert("You are correct");
    }
    else {
        alert("Please try again");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="textBox"  value="" />
<br/>
<button onclick="submitMe()" id="testButton" >Submit Response </button>
<br/>
```

Eventually these words will be loaded into a database. I'm just testing a concept now. Any guidance on this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Clarification questions: 1) wordOrder is an array that contains the strings / words the user must enter (in order) to complete the task? 2) you want the words object to only contain words and their translations as key:value pairs, not what it currently is - as separated by tasks too, right?

Comment: right. 1) `wordOrder` is an array that will contain the correct order of disparate words given that task, 2)Yes. But what do you mean `words` object is not currently separated Chinese:Translation by key:value pairs?

Comment: Cool. All I meant by #2 was that currently your `words` object has Chinese:Translation elements inside `task1` and `task2` objects - is this what you will want in the end? Or will you want the `words` object to be ONLY filled with the Chinese:Translation key:value pairs, NOT inside separate `task1`, `task2`, `task3`, etc. objects?

Comment: I wanted to assign them by task. But if I'm just making a database of words anyway, would it be easier to not separate them by task?

Comment: Honestly I think it would be easiest to hardcode the correct phrasing into one object [probs the `words` object] and then randomize the location each translation pair appears as you output them below the submit button [so it doesn't outright give them the correct sentence]. Otherwise it seems like you will need multiple objects with similar data. Does that make sense?

Comment: @TyrannicalTyrannosaurus Ah, they aren't actually selecting from a list of sentence choices that are scrambled... they are actually constructing the sentence by clicking on words in a word bank (sent by the words object). So I was trying to find a way I suppose to just grab the words from the `words` object and put them in order for the given task

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45152/discussion-between-tyrannical-tyrannosaurus-and-growler)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my changes / updates that hopefully helped:

html: added this div for the word bank below the submit button

```
<div id="words"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var currentTask = 1,
    numberOfTasks = 0;

// assuming "Ni", "Hao", "Wo", "Shi" is the correct phrasing for task 1:
var words = {
    "task1" :
    {
        'Ni'    : 'you',
        'Hao'   : 'good',
        'Wo'    : 'I',
        'Shi'   : 'am'  
    },
    "task2" :
    {
        'Xie Xie' : 'Thanks',
        'Bu' : 'No',
        'Ke Qi' : 'Manners'
    }
}
// get number of tasks in words object
for (var key in words) {
    numberOfTasks++;
}

/*Check player sentence input to see if grammar is correct*/
submitMe = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
    var correctOrder = getWordOrder().join(' ').toLowerCase();
    if ($.trim(input.toLowerCase()) == correctOrder) {
        alert("You are correct");
        $('#textBox').val(''); // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174265/reset-textbox-value-in-javascript
        currentTask++;
        loadNextLevel();
    }
    else {
        alert("Please try again");
    }
}

loadNextLevel = function() {
    $('#words').empty();
    if (currentTask <= numberOfTasks) {
        var taskNum = "task" + currentTask,
            wordList = [];
        for (var word in words[taskNum]) {
            var temp = {};
            temp[word] = words[taskNum][word];
            wordList.push(temp);
        }
        wordList = shuffle(wordList);
        for (var i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
            for (var w in wordList[i]) {
                $('#words').append("<div class='word' onclick='addText(this)'>"+w+" : "+wordList[i][w]+"</div>");
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert('you win! a.k.a. there are no more tasks to complete');
    }
}

addText = function(me) {
    var chineseWord = $.trim(me.innerHTML.split(':')[0]);
    var textElement = document.getElementById('textBox');
    if (textElement.value.length > 0) {
        textElement.value += " ";
    }
    textElement.value += chineseWord;
}

getWordOrder = function() {
    var taskNum = "task" + currentTask,
        order = [];
    for (var word in words[taskNum]) {
        order.push(word);
    }
    return order;
}

shuffle = function(o){ //v1.0
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};

loadNextLevel();
```

css I added to make the word bank look better:

```
.word {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:2px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    float:left;
}

.word:active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[All put together here!](http://jsfiddle.net/Bs2Zx/4/) Let me know whatcha think!