# NewLine Code for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have here a working code regarding arrays but i want my input to display in new lines not a single row. I have tried \n but no luck.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>
        <title>Sample Array</title>
        <script>var index = 0;</script>
    </head> 

    <body>


        Input:
        <input type="text" id="input">
        <input type="button" value="GO" onClick="press(input.value)">

        <p id = "display">

        <script>

            var sample = new Array();

            function press(Number)
            {

                if ( Number != '' )
                {
                    sample[index] = Number;
                    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += sample[index] + "\n";
                    index++;

                }   

                else
                    alert("empty");
            }       

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want to code the newline within the document.getElementById. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i forgot about that. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dealing with HTML which treats most white space characters as a single space. Just concatenate a `<br>`:

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += sample[index] + "<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks alot! works like charm. Also i want to add something, is there any way to clear the input box after i press the button?

Comment: @MarcIntes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174265/reset-textbox-value-in-javascript

Comment: I can now continue with my project. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For the record, `document.getElementById('input').value = ''`, @MarcIntes. And it's safer to always use `getElementById`; referencing the id directly works on most (all?) browsers, but it's non-standard.